# Login multi user

Tags: user-management

I have already set up Ubuntu and logging in to  multiple users using SSH. Can I log in to multiple users at same time in Ubuntu 18.04 using the GUI as sometimes the GUI is useful?

Comment: it is called "multiseat". https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multiseat  See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054541/multiseat-on-ubuntu-18-04  Easiest method: 2 video cards or using a multi-head for 2 users. Also https://wiki.debian.org/Multi_Seat_Debian_HOWTO Mind that you will also like to have 2 keyboards and mice ;)

Comment: Here is a video with 6 on 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTKLU8eyAxs