# How can I make a Multiseat in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, multiseat

I need to do Multiseat on computers at work, but I don't understand anything about it or ubuntu/linux, I would like to have an easy tutorial to follow, I read a little bit about LightDM (but I still don't understand much).

- The computers must have 2 seats.
- 2 monitors for each seat.
- The computers have integrated intel video and 1 video card

Is it possible to multiseat? if yes, how?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177272/1222991) may help you with the multi-seat setup, but having two VMs running that people sign into may work better, particularly for systems that are using snap-based software 

Comment: Were you ever able to get multiseat working? If not, I can try to help you. You can either do it with a series of commands or there is a little program you can use that simplifies the process. Since this is for work, you might be required to not use any third party programs.

The short answer is yes, this will work. Further details will prove or disprove.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, this will work. I have seen come computers that disable the onboard video when you plug in a video card, and others that allow the use of both devices.  I have one here with an Intel onboard, and an AMD video card(you did not specify yours) and both video are working.

To be brief, in order to create multiseat set one video (onboard or pci-e, it should not matter) to seat zero and set the other for seat one.  The only requirement for creating seats is the video card itself.

One option for creating seats is to use loginctl on the terminal to do the seat assignments.

Another option for creating seats is to use EasySeats, which is a little UI built with Java that makes issuing commands unnecessary.