# How to setup Single GPU - Multiseat with ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: multiple-monitors, games, multiseat

*Background:*
I have 1 room setup with desktop pc with single GPU, two monitors and tv connected with long hdmi cable in same room.

What I want to do is use two monitors on desk for web browsing / working / gaming and dedicate tv for steam big-screen. There is no real obstacle moving big-screen to windowed mode, drag it to tv, make it full size again - every - single - time.

Real obstacle comes with games with no option to go windowed mode or choose monitor when they seem more or less pop on random screen or something between. This is rubbish.

Issue could be easily resolved with single gpu - multi seat setup, where TV have dedicated X session, account, steam, (autologin) and dedicated usb ports for controllers.

*History:*
I can see this was well supported some time ago with example lightdm with multiseat manager and all.

*Current state:*
all we have is unofficial, outdated manuals and videos presenting multi seat in action but after trying to accomplish multi-seat with ubuntu, lubuntu and popos for 3 days without any success, I feel totally helpless.

I really don't want to revert back to windows and buy 100$ russian-software.
Having decent multi-seat manager for Ubuntu would be a huge advantage and bring more windoze users to ubuntu community as similar setups been trending for some time now.

Q: Does anyone have validated manual / instructions to offer for setting up multiseat for Ubuntu 23.10?

Comment: I think/suspect part of the problem was multiseat was a bit of a hack, and relied on very specific things. I think rather than "why isn't a thing?" "How would I do it on (some modern version)" could be a good question.

Comment: You ask *why* this is not so, which is not a great question on this site, which [focuses on solving problems](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask), not opinions. I suggest that you [edit] your question to state what problems you want help in solving, and what you have done so far.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374159/how-can-i-make-a-multiseat-in-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts seems similar but unsatisfying in its answers

Comment: @vidarlo I edited the question title to make it more focused.